# SQL QUERY Multiple Tables Newby

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I am new to SQL and have the following task I'm trying to complete:
I need to create a query that will return a set of results based on a set of dates.  Here are my TABLES/columns:

**Order Line**

```
order_id,
line_no,
qty_shipped,
total_shipped_qty,
part_id,
part_description,
desired_ship_date,
ship_date,
customer_id
```

**Shipper**

```
packlist,
order_id
```

**Customer**

```
name,
customer_id
```

**Customer Order**

```
PO, 
order_id
```

I need my **output** to look like this:

```
packlist,
order_id,
line_no,
total_shipped_qty,
part_id, 
part_description,
name,
po,
desired_ship_date,
ship_date,
```

So far I have come up with a query below that gets me all the column data I need from the Order Line Table based on a set of dates.  I'm having trouble joining the other tables together to get the rest of the columns I need in my output.  Specifically packlist, po, and name from their tables.  I need to run this query first:

```
SELECT ORDER_ID,
       LINE_NO,
       TOTAL_SHIPPED_QTY,
       PART_DESCRIPTION,
       DESIRED_SHIP_DATE,
       SHIP_DATE,
       TOTAL_SHIPPED_QTY
FROM   ORDER_LINE
WHERE  [SHIP_DATE] BETWEEN 'XXXX/XX/XX' AND 'XXXX/XX/XX'
```

Based on the results above I need to pull in the rest of the data from the other tables.  Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a `INNER JOIN` between all the tables is what you need

```
SELECT S.PACKLIST,
       O.ORDER_ID,
       O.TOTAL_SHIPPED_QTY,
       O.PART_ID,
       O.PART_DESCRIPTION,
       C.NAME,
       CO.PO,
       O.DESIRED_SHIP_DATE,
       O.SHIP_DATE
FROM   ORDERLINE O
       JOIN CUSTOMERS C
         ON C.CUSTOMER_ID = O.CUSTOMER_ID
       JOIN SHIPPER S
         ON S.ORDER_ID = O.ORDER_ID
       JOIN CUSTOMERORDER CO
         ON CO.ORDER_ID = O.ORDER_ID
WHERE  O.[SHIP_DATE] BETWEEN 'XXXX/XX/XX' AND 'XXXX/XX/XX'
```

Comment: Thank you everyone for you posts.  My query is now completing successfully but i get no data on the output.  The columns are there, just no data.  Any ideas?  Thanks

Comment: @Gabe - do you have data in all the tables.

Comment: I sure do.  All the tables have tons of data.

Comment: @Gabe Try changing the data in `between`. Makes sure every table has at-least one common order_id

Comment: Thats my problem, my common id's aren't all the same.  I'll do some more looking.  Thanks

Comment: @Gabe Even If one common order_id is present in all the tables you will get result.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT s.packlist, o.Order_ID, 
o.total_shipped_qty,o.Part_ID, o.Part_Description, co.PO,
c.Name, o.Desired_Ship_Date, o.Ship_Date 
from OrderLine o 
inner join Customers c on c.Customer_ID = o.Customer_ID 
inner join Shipper s on s.Order_ID = o.Order_ID
inner join CustomerOrders co on co.Order_ID = o.Order_ID
WHERE  o.[SHIP_DATE] BETWEEN 'XXXX/XX/XX' AND 'XXXX/XX/XX'
```

I don't think you need to join on CustomerOrders at this point.